# How to get parent content?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I tried this and it displays actually the current page content not parent content:

```
<?php
   $my_postid = 3105;
   $content_post = get_post($my_postid);
   $content = $content_post->post_content;
   $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
   echo $content;
?>
```

And also tried the following but i get a warning:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for get_page(), called in:
```

Code:

```
  <?php 
     $page = get_page();
     $parentID = $page['post_parent'];
     if($parentID != '0') {
       $parentPage = get_page($parentID);
       $parentContent = $parentPage['post_content'];
       $parentContent =  apply_filters('the_content', $parentContent); 
       echo $parentContent;
     } 
  ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
global $post;
if ($post->post_parent) {
    $parent = get_page($post->post_parent);
    echo apply_filters('the_content', $parent->post_content);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, global $post; is what I needed. posted my own answer which is along yours lines.

Answer (score 1):

Given some loaded post:

```
$id = 3105;
$content_post = get_post($id);
```

You can fetch its parent:

```
$parent_id = $content_post->post_parent; // Will be 0 if the post has no parent
$parent = get_post($parent_id);
```

And output the content:

```
echo $parent->post_content;
```

Comment: Check the value of `$parent_id` to make sure the post you're looking at has a parent. If `$parent_id` is nonzero, `var_dump($parent)` and see what the parent post object looks like.

Comment: it definitely has a parent tho, I have assign it on the admin

Comment: actually, maybe that my parent content is actually a gallery with images attached?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked at the end, the key was to use global $post;

```
<?php
 global $post;
 $args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
'post_status' => null,
'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
'order_by' => 'menu_order',
'order' => 'ASC'
);
 $attachments = get_posts($args);
 if($attachments)
  {
   echo '<ul class="imagelist">';
   foreach($attachments as $attachment)
 {
   echo '<li>';
   $large = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'large');
   $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'thumbnail');
   echo '<a href="'. $large[0] .'">' . $thumb . '</a>';
   echo '</li>';
 }
  echo '</ul>';
 }
?>
```